# Add activation for each seeded User in Sentinel (Laravel)

Tags: php, database, laravel, seeding, sentinel

Using Laravel's database seeding I'm adding 10 random users, when I try to log in with these users Sentinel gives me an error that the account has to be activated first, what I want to do now is to (when I'm seeding) make an activation for each users that is being seeded, here's my DatabaseSeeder:

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\User::class, 10)->create()->each(function($user) {
        DB::table('activations')->insert([
            'user_id' => $user->user_id,
            'code' => str_random(24),
            'completed' => '1'
        ]);
    });
}
```

The problem I get is that the database is being filled with random users and 10 activations, but all user id's are 0

Here the user factory:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'id' => random_int(100000, 999999),
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
    ];
});
```

Comment: is bot the `id` column auto incremental in users table ?

Comment: No sorry I didn't mention that, the user ID's are random strings

Comment: make it auto incremental

Comment: Can you add the user factory method?

Comment: Added it @Marabo

Comment: Just add the user_id column in database as primary and auto incremental

Comment: you get 0 as id in the users table or as user_id in the activations tale ?

Comment: @Maraboc as id in the activations table

Comment: sorry i didn't get you is it the id or the user_id in the activations table ?

Comment: Yeah the point is that when I make a user the users get ID's between 100000 and 999999 (for explainable reasons), the activations table however does get incremental ID's (so 1 till 10 in our case) but the user_id field in the activations table won't get the $user->id of the User instead it always returns 0.

Comment: now it's clear ;), do you have a relationship on the user model with activations?

Comment: No not yet, perhaps because Sentinel always automatically makes activations when registering a user

Answer (score 0):

Add a factory for the activations :

```
$factory->define(App\Activation::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'code' => str_random(24),
        'completed' => '1'
    ];
});
```

And add the relation in the user model :

```
public function activation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Activation');
}
```

Then you can do like this :

```
factory(App\User::class, 10)->create()->each(function($user) {
    $user->activation()->save(factory(App\Activation::class)->make());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is easier method that i implement in my code is

```
     \App\Models\User::factory(100)->create()->each(function($user) {
    $users = Sentinel::findById($user->id);
    $activation = Activation::create($users);
    Activation::complete($users,$activation->code); 
});
```

note: before implement this code in your seeder must check import Sentinel in header